# How to count the occurrence of each key within an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Say I have an array of objects like so:

```
[{"taco":"","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":"true"}, 
{"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"true","beans":""}, 
{"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":""}, 
{"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":"true"}]
```

I need to count the occurrence of each element and return in it in an array

```
[3, 0, 1, 2]
```

any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

I have attempted

```
var a = datasets.reduce(function (item, index) {
    if (typeof item[index] == 'undefined') {
        item[index] = 1;
    } else {
        item[index] += 1;
    }
    return item;
}, {});
```

could not get anything like that to work so i attempted converting it to json and then removing any key: value pairs with no value then counting remaining ones but have had no success with that either

```
function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];

    var headers = [];
    for (var i=0; i < table[0].rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table[0].rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
    }

    for (var i=1; i< table[0].rows.length; i++) {

        var tableRow = table[0].rows[i];
        var rowData = {};

        for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
        }
        data.push(rowData);
    }
    return data
    }

    function removeEmpty(jsonObj) {
      var newObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsonObj);
      for (var i = 0; i < newObj.length; i++) {
        var value = newObj[i];
        if (jsonObj[value] === null || jsonObj[value] === undefined) {
          delete jsonObj[value];
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the Javascript? The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: On what is the 'total amount' based? What do the numbers in your output array refer to?

Comment: please explain your output

Comment: sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: i either get [1, 1, 1, 1] or in the cleaning case something along the lines of [true, "", "", true], i understand why but i cant think of a way to do this

Comment: @JandreiPitti please edit your question and explain why you want this output.

Comment: @JandreiPitti now it's good to answer. Added answer in answer section you can check there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can try this**

You can do it with `reduce()`.

What i have done is first i check is the **`object property of current element`** if it is already in **`output object`**. If it's present than i check the value of **`current element property`**. if it is true than i increment the property of **`output object`** by `1`.

If the **`object property of current element`** is not available in output than i check for the value of **`current element property`**. if it is true i assign output object property with value `1`. if false i assign output object property with `0`.

```js
let obj = [{"taco":"","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":"true"}, 
{"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"true","beans":""}, 
{"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":""}, 
{"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":"true"}]

let op = obj.reduce((output,current)=>{
  for(let key in current){
    if( output[key] ){
      if( current[key] ) output[key]+=1;
    } else {
      if( current[key] ){
        output[key] = 1;
      } else{
        output[key] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
},{})

console.log(op);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, i see where i went wrong! sorry about the initial vague post. I was headed in the right direction at least, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var data = [{
      taco: "",
      burrito: "",
      scone: "",
      beans: "true"
    },
    {
      taco: "true",
      burrito: "",
      scone: "true",
      beans: ""
    },
    {
      taco: "",
      burrito, "true",
      scone: "",
      beans: "",
      },  {
        taco: "true",
        burrito: "",
        scone: "",
        beans: "true"
      }]

    var total = [0, 0, 0, 0];

    data.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (obj.taco) {
        total[0]++;
      }
      if (burrito) {
        total[1]++;
      }
      if (obj.scone) {
        total[2]++;
      }
      if (obj.beans) {
        total[3]++;
      }
    })

    console.log(total)
```

Comment: This way would work however with the caveat that you rely on a fixed, known set of keys

Comment: I upvoted, but I marked the other one as the answer because it covers a wider range of use cases and objects, thank you for answering though! I definitely see how this would work as well

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and then loop through the keys of each object. Then increment the `key` of the `countObject` if it already exists or assign it zero.

This is dynamic. Even if one of the object has an extra `key`, it will count them. This doesn't expect all the items of array to have the same keys.

```js
var array = [
 {"taco":"","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":"true"}, 
 {"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"true","beans":""}, 
 {"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":""}, 
 {"taco":"true","burrito":"","scone":"","beans":"true"} 
]

var countObject = {};

array.forEach(item => {
    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        if (item[key] === "true")
            countObject[key] = countObject[key] + 1 || 1
        else
            countObject[key] = countObject[key] || 0
    })
})

console.log(countObject); // get the key and count pair
console.log(Object.values(countObject)); // get the counts in an array
```